# FireDac field not found

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE5 and SQL Server 2012. I have this problem : When my form is opened I connect to database and I assign values to my fields, like this –

```
dbeCustomer.DataSource := DataForm.SQLDS;
dbeCustomer.DataField := 'Customer';
```

All works well, until I try to run the stand alone .exe program. Then I get an error – ‘Field ‘Customer’ not found’. That is, if I run the compiled program from the Debug folder, all works just fine. When I run this program outside the Debug folder I get an error.
If I modify my code this way everything works fine again in every place :

```
dbeCOwner.DataSource := DataForm.SQLDS;

try
    dbeCOwner.DataField := 'COwner';
   except
    dbeCOwner.DataField := 'COwner';
   end;
```

Any ideas how that could be? Thank you.

Comment: The location of your .Exe shouldn't make any difference to this. The most likely cause is something in your code that you haven't included in the q.  Please add to your q the complete code of the procedure/function which contains the code you've quoted.   If the unit isn't more than a few dozen lines, you might as well include the whole of it.  Also, when the exception occurs, use View | Debug Windows | Call stack to see where it's happening.

Comment: "The location of your .Exe shouldn't make any difference to this" Yes, that's what I thought. However .exe file behaves itself differently depending on whether it is in Debug folder or anywhere else, that's strange...

Comment: Well, move your .Exe from the Debug folder to somewhere else and run it from the IDE under the debugger.  That should reveal why you're getting the exception.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Well, you still haven't added any more code to your q which might help readers maybe spot the problem.

Comment: To debug your exe outside of the debug folder, change output directory in the projet options.

Comment: I don't know what code to show - there are 2500 lines in my .pas file. The problem (as I see it) may be everywhere. Thank you very much, MartynA and Heinz Z.

Answer (score 0):

With only the information you've provided, it's impossible to guess
what might be causing your problem.  Since your app's behaviour
evidently depends on where it is located when it is run, the obvious 
thing to do is to run it from the IDE but in a different directory
than your Debug one.

1. Open a Windows Explorer on your project's Debug directory.  Move everything 
   in it to your project directory.
2. In the IDE, go to View | Project Manager.
3. Select `Debug`, right-click it and select `Edit` from the pop-up.
4. Set the `Output directory` to your project directory.
5. In the IDE, go to Tools | Options and in the pop-up, go to 
   `Embarcadero debuggers | Language Exceptions` and check the box `Notify on language exceptions`.
6. Build the app and check that your `Debug` folder is still empty from step 1.
7. Run the app & debug.

Answer (score -1):

I try a guess:
1. You have switched off "stop on exception" in the IDE
2. Your Application is missing a DLL or a database file wich is only in your debug directory

I guess this, because you eat the exception in your example code, so that you will not see any exception.

Comment: None of your guesses are correct, I think…
Here is what I do
`    1) Connecting to SQL Server
    2) Composing some SQL query (sqlStmt  := 'SELECT TOP 50 *   FROM MTable ORDER BY nNo';)
    3) Assigning values to my TDBTexts
    4) Run SQL query`
In this scenario I get an error ‘Field ‘Some field’ not found’, if I run .exe file outside Debug folder.
But if change line 4 with line 3 all again works fine.

Comment: You absolutly right. And If I had read your question correctly, I could know it before. So sorry for that.